# Play Store crashes when trying to open "Manage Instant Apps"

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, instant-apps

Well, it's not like I want to use instant apps but this is frustrating me either way. When I open Play Store and go to Settings and try to open "Manage Instant Apps", the Play Store just crashes and starts again with a message.

I'm on stock Marshmallow, Play Services for Instant Apps version is 1.19.

Here is the log when it comes to crashing:

```
08-30 01:39:42.436  2589  2787 I ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/.SettingsActivity} from uid 10049 on display 0
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.vending, PID: 4385
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.SettingsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1801)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3951)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3912)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4235)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4203)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.finsky.settings.SettingsActivity.onPreferenceTreeClick(SourceFile:299)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1004)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1188)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3105)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4096)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
08-30 01:39:42.466  4385  4385 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
08-30 01:39:42.515  2589  3354 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.settings.SettingsActivity
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am pretty sure The error: E AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor/com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.SettingsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?  Means that the package was not properly declared and they need to fix the coding.

Comment: @Bo Lawson yes I know that, but is there way to fix it? Or it's up to them ? In that case can  I report error to them, if yes where?

Comment: Yes, you can report it to them. Within the play store in the side menu on the bottom. Go to help and feedback and then go to the bottom were it says feed back. You can file a bug report with logs there.